# Android SDK Manager doesn't show all packages

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

Android SDK manager is not displaying all the old + new API's, its just only showing **API 17** and **API 19,**

Thanks in Advance,

[image]

Comment: you have selected installed in the show line....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `SDK Platform Tools 19.0.1` first. Then you will be able to see all the API platform packages.

Comment: Thanks ZygoteInit, gave Up arrow brada

Comment: Why is it like this? Each time I were opening SDK Manager, It seemed fetches some new reposotories never did before and displayed new packages (even as sub-packages of currently installed APIs). i.e I had the sysem images at the 4th / 5th time of lunching the SDK manager. Didn't know they even exist untill got error through creating AVDs.

Comment: The very first thing you should do during a fresh Android SDK installation is download `Platform Tools` first. This contains the latest URLs' for the SDK platform packages. And yes, the SDK manager is routinely updated with new packages as they are made available for download.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once..I just deleted all that I had installed already, closed the SDK manager and when I opened it again it showed all the old APIs. Hope that helps